# How to pass session between browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chromecast

I have created a site with Laravel. I'm trying to cast the site to a chromecast device as a permanent display on TV. I use this [url cast receiver](https://github.com/DeMille/url-cast-receiver) to achieve this. The problem is that my site requires authentication so when I send the iframe, the chromecast internal browser loads the site but it gets stuck on the login page. And since I can't control the preview display, I can't login there.

Is there a way to pass the logged in session from phone into the sent site in chromecast?

I was thinking of creating some temporary session id, stored in DB in the user's table and if this session id is present in the URL, PHP will create the logged in state for the user. I know this might have some security issues but I can't think of other way to fix this problem with chromecast.

Any other ideas will be appreciated.

Note: Mirroring device is not ideal because the phone needs to have the display on all the time to mirror and that's not feasible. I want people cast the site without their phone's display on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel allows you to easily create "signed" URLs to named routes. These URLs have a "signature" hash appended to the query string which allows Laravel to verify that the URL has not been modified since it was created. Signed URLs are especially useful for routes that are publicly accessible yet need a layer of protection against URL manipulation.

For example, you can use a signed URL to login with user data. To create a signed URL to a named route, use the `signedRoute` method of the `URL` facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

return URL::signedRoute('chromecastLogin', ['user' => 1]);
```

If you would like to generate a temporary signed route URL that expires, you may use the `temporarySignedRoute` method:

```
return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'chromecastLogin', now()->addMinutes(60), ['user' => 1]
);
```

**Validating Signed Route Requests**

To verify that an incoming request has a valid signature, you should call the `hasValidSignature` method on the incoming `Request`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/chromecastLogin/{user}', function (Request $request) {
    if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401);
    }

    // login the user
})->name('chromecastLogin');
```

Comment: Interesting! What file do I add `Url::signedRoute` ?

Comment: You have to do it in a controller, generate this signed url and then show it to the user to click on it to login to chomeCast.

You can also generate and redirect it directly.

Comment: Ok, so this works for PHP but I'm also using Vue and all calls are unauthorized.  Do you know why?

Comment: I followed this https://www.dwightwatson.com/posts/autologin-with-laravel-56 and that bypassed the login nicely. Thanks! But it only works with 'location' type, not the iframe which takes away the control